# How to retry a failed action?

Tags: spring, spring-statemachine

I went through Spring Statemachine documentation but did not find clear answers for some scenarios. I will greatly appreciate if some one can clarify my questions.

Scenario1: How to retry errors related to action failures? Lets say I have the following states S1, S2 and S3 and when we transition from S1 to S2 I want to perform action A2. If action A2 fails I want to retry it with some time intervals. Is that possible using Spring StateMachine?

Consider AWS state machine Step Functions for example. All work in the step functions States are done using Task. And Task can be configured for retry.

```
transitions
            .withExternal()
                .source(States.S1)
                .target(States.S2)
                .event(Events.E1)
                .action(action());
```

Scenario 2: Lets say Statemachine has states S1, S2 and S3. The current state is S2. If the server goes down on startup will the Statemachine execution pick up from where it left off or we will have to do it all over again?

Scenario 3: When a Guard returns false (possibly because of error condition) and prevents a transition what happens next?

Comment: scenario 2 and 3 are not related to retry logic. They are totally separate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to retry a failed action?

There are two types of actions in Spring State Machine - transition actions and state actions. In *scenario 1* you're talking about transition action.

When you specify a transition action, you can also specify an error handler if the action fails. This is clearly documented in the spring state machine [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#statemachine-config-transition-actions-errorhandling).

```
.withExternal()
    .source(States.S1)
    .target(States.S2)
    .event(Events.E1)
    .action(action(), errorAction());
```

In your `errorAction()` method you can implement your logic.
Possible options are:

- transition to an earlier state and go the same path
- transition to a specific state (e.g. retry state) where you can have your retry logic (e.g. Task/Executor that retries the action N times, and transition to other states (e.g. action success => go normal flow; action failed after N retries => transition to a failure terminal state)

There's also the [official Tasks example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#statemachine-examples-tasks), that demonstrates recovery/retry logic ([source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/tree/master/spring-statemachine-samples/tasks)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried both the options you mentioned above for retry. If possible can you please also provide answer for Scenario 2 and Scenario 3 just for the completeness of the answer to the above question. After that I will accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @MuneerY Scenario 2 and 3 are not related to your main question - I don't see how they bring "completeness" - actually the opposite - they will bring confusion. Maybe consider asking those in separate questions.